# What is <cycle> in data?

Tags: ocaml, evaluation

(I use OCaml version 4.02.3)

I defined a type `self`

```
# type self = Self of self;;
type self = Self of self
```

and its instance `s`

```
# let rec s = Self s;;
val s : self = Self <cycle>
```

Since [OCaml is a strict language](https://ocaml.org/learn/description.html#Evaluationregime), I expected defining `s` will fall into infinite recursion. But the interpreter said `s` has a value and it is `Self <cycle>`.

I also applied a function to `s`.

```
# let f (s: self) = 1;;
val f : self -> int = <fun> 
# f s;;
- : int = 1
```

It seems `s` is not evaluated before the function application (like in non-strict language).

How OCaml deal with cyclic data like `s`? `Self <cycle>` is a normal form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OCaml is indeed an eager language, however `s` is a perfectly valid and fully evaluated term that happens to contain a cycle. For instance, this code yields the expected result:

```
let f (Self Self x) = x
f s == s;;
```

More precisely, the memory representation of constructors with at n arguments are boxed and read like this:

```
⋅—————————————————————————————————————————————⋅
| header | field[0] | field[1] | ⋯ | fiekd[n] |
⋅—————————————————————————————————————————————⋅
```

The header contains metadata whereas `field[k]` is an OCaml value, i.e. either an integer or a pointer. In the case of `s`, `Self` has only one argument, and thus only one field `field[0]`. The value of `field[0]` is then simply a pointer towards the start of the block. The term `s` is thus perfectly representable in OCaml.

Moreover, the toplevel printer is able to detect this kind of cycles and print an `<cycle>` to avoid falling into an infinite recursion when printing the value of `s`. Here, `<cycle>`, like `<abstr>` or `<fun>`, represents just a kind of value that the toplevel printer cannot print.

Note, however, that cyclical value will trigger infinite recursion in many situations, for instance `f s = s` where `(=)` is the structural equality
and not the physical one `(i.e. (==))` triggers such recursion, another example would be

```
let rec ones = 1 :: ones;; (* prints [1;<cycle>] *)
let twos = List.map ((+) 1) ones;; (* falls in an infinite recursion *)
```

Comment: <cycle> is a feature introduced in v4.0.2? With [Try OCaml](https://try.ocamlpro.com/) (v4.0.1) `s` cannot be defined.

Comment: The printing of <cycle> is only a feature of the toplevel printer, that was indeed introduced in 4.02 (cf. https://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=6228). However, cyclic values can be defined since OCaml 1.0 (see http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.04/extn.html#sec217); nevertheless it may be possible that Try Ocaml has some difficulties with such values.